# How to took middle time range from wav . Python

Tags: python, numpy, audio, wav

I need to extract  **exaclly 8 seconds from the middle of the audio data** from the wav. file with lenght 0:27 sec.

--All what I did already, it took the middle 9 sec by divided wav. file on 3 parts and took the middle one, but it's 9s I need 8s.

And how find a **number of bits in that numpy array**?

```
import scipy.io.wavfile
import pyaudio
import numpy as np

(samplRate,data)=scipy.io.wavfile.read('Track48.wav')

print

CHANNELS=2

p= pyaudio.PyAudio()
                        #
nine_sec=len(data)/3
eight_sec=2*len(data)/3

stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                         channels=CHANNELS,
                         rate=44100,
                         output=True
                         )

cuted_data=data[nine_sec:eight_sec]

newdata = cuted_data.astype(np.int16).tostring()
stream.write(newdata)

print(cuted_data)
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please use your working code as an example

Comment: why aren't you using the `samplRate` you read from the .wav file? for the  .wav format it is an integer: the samples per second

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pydub` to slice middle 8 seconds very easily.
Details on [pydub are here](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub)
And you can install as `pip install pydub`

I had a wav file of 348 sec duration whose middle 8 seconds are sliced.

```
>>> song.duration_seconds
348.05551020408166
```

You can also use different file formats such as `wav`, `mp3`, `m4a`, `ogg` etc. for import (convert to data-segments) and export.

**Source Code**

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

song = AudioSegment.from_wav("music.wav")

#slice middle eight seconds of audio
midpoint = song.duration_seconds // 2

left_four_seconds = (midpoint - 4) * 1000 #pydub workds in milliseconds
right_four_seconds = (midpoint + 4) * 1000 #pydub workds in milliseconds

eight_sec_slice = song[left_four_seconds:right_four_seconds ]

#Play slice
play(eight_sec_slice )

#or save to file
eight_sec_slice.export("eight_sec_slice.wav", format="wav")
```

As you can see length of middle 8 seconds slice is exactly as desired.

```
>>> eight_sec_slice.duration_seconds
8.0
```

Comment: Wow it work very well , thank you so much for your help. I tried to found the middle of wav. file by divided lenght of data array by 2. Sampling freq in Hz - 44100 , its second in extent -1 ( 44100 samples in 1 sec) and I add +4*44100 samples in 1 way , and - 44100 *4 in another way. And I thoughts its a exactly 8 sec . But your way is much understandable.

Comment: `pydub` does similar work in the background. You may want to check API to gain more insights. Also, It is customary to accept the question so that it doesn't appear unanswered on SO. Up voting will be appreciated as well although I think  you need 15 reputation for up-voting. accepting questions  adds reputation to you account as well. Here is a SO discussion on how to gain reputation for new user : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139661/how-to-get-initial-reputation-on-stack-overflow-with-the-new-user-restrictions-i

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but someone may like the solution i want to offer which uses numpy only. No need of `pydub`.

```
import scipy.io.wavfile as wavfile

fs, data - wavefile.read("Track48.wav")

# number of samples N
N = data.shape[0]

# Convert seconds to samples
eight_secs_in_samples = float(fs)*8 # time = number_of_samples / rate

midpoint_sample = N//2 # Midpoint of sample

# substract 4 seconds from midpoint
left_side = midpoint_sample-(eight_secs_in_samples//2) 

# Add 4 seconds from midpoint up
right_side = midpoint_sample + (eight_secs_in_samples//2)

# The midpoint of samples is therefore:
mid8secs = array_data[int(left_side):int(right_side)] # this range contains the required samples
# Save the file
wavfile.write("eightSecSlice.wav",fs,mid8secs)
```